# Simple User/Password authentication for HiveServer2 (without Kerberos/LDAP)

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

How to provide a simple propertyfile or database user/password authentication for HiveServer2?

I already found [this](http://julingks.tistory.com/entry/Hive-Authorization) presentation about this, but it's not in English :(.
On the [Cloudera reference manual](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.1/CDH4-Security-Guide/cdh4sg_topic_9_1.html) they talk about the `hive.server2.authentication` property. It supports `CUSTOM` implementations of the interface `hive.server2.custom.authentication`.

How to implement that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In essence, you have to provide a java application that can perform your authentication.  Maybe you're authing to a mysql or postgres database, or a flat file, etc.  You need to provide a jar that can implement the org.apache.hive.service.auth.PasswdAuthenticationProvider interface.

A simple example:

```
package org.apache.hive.service.auth.PasswdAuthenticationProvider.SampleAuth;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.security.sasl.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.hive.service.auth.PasswdAuthenticationProvider;

/*
 javac -cp $HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-service-0.12.0-cdh5.0.0-beta-2.jar SampleAuthenticator.java -d .
 jar cf sampleauth.jar hive
 cp sampleauth.jar $HIVE_HOME/lib/.
*/


public class SampleAuthenticator implements PasswdAuthenticationProvider {

  Hashtable<String, String> store = null;

  public SampleAuthenticator () {
    store = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    store.put("user1", "passwd1");
    store.put("user2", "passwd2");
  }

  @Override
  public void Authenticate(String user, String  password)
      throws AuthenticationException {

    String storedPasswd = store.get(user);

    if (storedPasswd != null && storedPasswd.equals(password))
      return;

    throw new AuthenticationException("SampleAuthenticator: Error validating user");
  }

}
```

And then in hive-site.xml, use your newly created custom authentication jar:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
  <value>CUSTOM</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.server2.custom.authentication.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hive.service.auth.PasswdAuthenticationProvider.SampleAuth</value>
</property>
```