# Custom authentication in Impala (without kerberos/LDAP)

Tags: authentication, hive, cloudera, impala

We have a big data cluster that we have created by directly installing the **tarballs** from Cloudera website. We are currently using (**Hive, Impala, Hadoop, Spark, Kafka**). In the current setup we don't have any **authentication/authorization** setup.

We are in the process of adding authentication/authorization however we decided to not use Kerberos to avoid the hassle of setting up a KDC server.

We were able to setup **Sentry** for authorization and for authentication we are using **Hive Custom authentication** where in we validate user credentials through an internal REST API as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186973/simple-user-password-authentication-for-hiveserver2-without-kerberos-ldap/22307063)

We are trying to setup similar authentication mechanism for **Impala** however we have not been able to figure out a way to do Custom authentication in Impala.

Please let us know if apart from **LDAP/Kerberos** there is an alternative way to authenticate a user, something that is equivalent of Hive Custom authentication.